# Not in Prolog and use of Bagof

Tags: prolog

I have database like this:

```
movie(matrix,wachowski,thriller).
movie(terminator, cameron, thriller).
movie(Gladiator, scott, costume).
movie(star wars, lucas, fantasy).
movie(star trek, abrams, fantasy).
```

And I want to know who direct fantasy film except Abrams.
I suppose I need to use 'not' predicate, but I don't know exactly how it works.

```
?- movie(X,not(abrams),fantasy).
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

One more query is what kind of films is not a thriller:

```
?- movie(X,_,not(thriller)).
```

Still not working.

Next problem is I need to use predicate `direct(Director, listsOfMovie)` based on bagof.

```
?- direct(Director, listsOfMovie) :- bagof(Director,movie(Director,listsOfMovie,_), listsOfMovie).
```

Still without success :(

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use of `not`**

You can't use Prolog predicates like functions. `not/1` is a predicate which accepts a query as an argument. So this isn't doing what you think:

```
movie(X,not(abrams),fantasy).
```

This is querying `movie` with a second argument of `not(abrams)`. You don't have any facts or predicates that match `movie(_, not(_), _)` so it will always fail.

If you want to know which films were not thrillers, you might render it:

```
movie(X, _, Type),
Type \= thriller.`
```

Using `not`, it might be:

```
not( movie(X, _, thriller) ).
```

If you wanted the syntax of `movie(_, not(_), _)` to work, you could write a predicate for it:

```
movie( Name, not(Director), Type ) :-
    movie(Name, D, Type),
    D \= Director.
```

Now we have either a fact or a predicate head that matches the form, `movie(_, not(_), _)`, and then the query, `movie(X, not(abrams), Y)` would work. But it's not normally done this way.

**Using `bagof/3`**

Let's look at your use of `bagof`. In the simplest case, `bagof` is supposed to take three arguments:

```
bagof(X, {query involving X}, ListOfSatisfingXs)
```

So `bagof` will run the *{query involving X}* generating each `X` that makes it true, creating `ListOfSatisfingXs`, a unique, sorted list of such instantiations of `X`. In other words, `ListOfSatisfingXs` is the unique, sorted values of `X` that make `{query involving X}` succeed.

In your case, you've gotten the arguments to `bagof` a bit mixed up:

```
direct(Director, listsOfMovie) :-
    bagof(Director, movie(Director, listsOfMovie, _), listsOfMovie).
```

Here, you're reusing your `Director` argument as your `bagof` argument, which is not good (since it's not intended). Since you're looking for a list of movies, the first argument should represent the movie. Your query to `movie` is using `listsOfMovie`, your intended target argument to hold the list result, which it shouldn't. And finally, `listsOfMovie` is an atom, not a variable, since it doesn't start with a capital letter.

The corrected version would be:

```
director_movies(Director, ListOfMovies) :-
    bagof(Movie, movie(Director, Movie, _), ListOfMovies).
```

Here, the `bagof` is getting the *Unique, sorted list of `Movie` values such that `movie(Director, Movie, _)` is true and providing that resulting list in `ListOfMovies`.

Comment: Thansk a lot, but what about bagof? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @user3136858 it's not clear what you want your `director` predicate to do with `bagof`. Are you wanting to get the list of movies for a given director, or the list of directors for a given movie or list of movies?

Comment: Lists of movies for given director :)